# MySQL Insert into post_meta with select and join - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So, I'm trying to run a SQL operation:

```
INSERT INTO wp4t_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT a.post_id, '_attached_image', b.ID
FROM wp4t_postmeta a 
INNER JOIN wp4t_posts b ON a.meta_value WHERE a.meta_key="_content_field_42" 
= b.guid
```

Essentially, I need the wp4t_postmeta table updated with a post ID, meta key (attached_image), and meta_value.

I need the meta_value to come from wp4t_posts ID, when the meta_value for meta_key _content_field_42 in wp4t_postmeta matches the guid of wp4t_posts.

I was at first running out of size in the tmp dir everytime I tried to run it, so I added a limit to test it:

```
INSERT INTO wp4t_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT a.post_id, '_attached_image', b.ID
FROM wp4t_postmeta a 
INNER JOIN wp4t_posts b ON a.meta_value WHERE a.meta_key="_content_field_42" 
= b.guid LIMIT 10;
```

Now I am getting the error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

I understand this is the meta_id auto increment table from wp4t_postmeta, but I thought if I didn't include it, it would auto auto-increment?

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, is there a better way to write this query?

Update.... Making progress:

```
INSERT INTO wp4t_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT postmeta.post_id, '_attached_image', posts.ID
FROM wp4t_postmeta AS postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp4t_posts AS posts ON postmeta.meta_value = posts.guid  
WHERE postmeta.meta_key="_content_field_42"
AND posts.post_type="attachment"
```

EDIT.... Still evlolving:

```
INSERT INTO wp4t_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT postmeta.post_id, '_attached_image', posts.ID 
FROM wp4t_postmeta AS postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp4t_posts AS posts ON postmeta.meta_value = posts.guid 
AND postmeta.meta_key = '_content_field_42' 
WHERE posts.post_type="attachment"
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I appreciate the help @str

Comment: @LawrenceBlack make sure you don't have any triggers registered

Comment: Can you do `show create` for both table and include the result in your question? that'll help more

Comment: @LawrenceBlack, you should provide feedback on Rick's answer

Comment: I dont understand, how he doesnt hav 500 reps but can still hav bounty of 500?

Comment: @Omkaar.K - Stack Overfart deducts the bounty from your rep. And, they don't even give it back to you if you don't reward it. Sadly, the other answer besides mine was totally incorrect. I answered it, but I can't give the bounty to myself. Win some, lose some.

Comment: The "Still evolving" made no substantive change:  `INNER JOIN .. ON x WHERE y AND z` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN .. ON x AND y WHERE z`.

Comment: @RickJames , well, I get that now, but when you're stuck on a programming issue, you'll rewrite the query seven ways from Sunday... Added answer below. I simply didn't have AutoIncrement on.

Comment: @LawrenceBlack - 500 does not elicit much more response than the basic 50.  Next time, be more cautious; it will be less embarrassing.

Comment: But seriously, can someone explain the 5 downvotes? lol - like, do people click a post for a bounty and then after looking at it decide, "nah..., lemme downvote this"... :/

Comment: Oh now I get it thank you @LawrenceBlack, but that is actually pretty sad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a hot second to answer this.

My query was correct.

I simply didn't have AutoIncrement turned on, because there was an invalid ID of 0, which I deleted.

EDIT: FINAL CORRECT QUERY

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO wp4t_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT postmeta.post_id, '_attached_image', posts.ID 
FROM wp4t_postmeta AS postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp4t_posts AS posts ON postmeta.meta_value = posts.guid 
WHERE postmeta.meta_key = '_content_field_42' 
AND posts.post_type="attachment"
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Worked on a VPS server with over 1MM tables in wp_postmeta - took some time, but it ran.

Comment: This explains _one_ of the things you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`ON a.meta_value` is "true" whenever `a.meta_value` is non-empty.  That is probably no what you wanted.  Perhaps this:

```
ON b.id = a.post_id
```

If this does not suffice, let's see a few relevant rows of both `a` and `b`.

Further explanation:  When the `ON` clause is always "true", you are building a temporary table that is *all* combinations of `a` and `b`.  If each has 10K rows, that would be a temp table with 100M rows.  That would probably overflow the space in the tmp directory.

But, if you get past that, you might get to 10K rows with the same `a.post_id`

But even that does not explain everything.  If I am not mistaken, `post_id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which does not normally contain `0`.  The only likely way to get `0` is to explicitly insert `0`.

But that is what you are doing.

OK, I can't deduce where the original `0` came from, but that is likely to be a clue into another problem.

Comment: @LawrenceBlack -- Yea, that's me, bro !

Comment: Possible bonus (not sure if it applies here):  `wp_postmeta` is rather inefficient as currently defined.  My notes on improving it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta